# Shiny updateRadioButtons cannot clear selected item

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app where change in a `selectInput` causes a change in choices available to the user in a `radioButtons` group. According to the [documentation on updateRadioButtons](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateRadioButtons.html),

> the selected item can be cleared by using `selected=character(0)`.

But, as demoed in the example below, this does not appear to work. If you watch the messages in the console while changing the inputs, you see the 'current color' never returns to a null state. Moreover, if you select 'red' then switch from 'a' to 'b', the value changes from '1' to '4' as if you had selected 'red' again. This is not the desired behavior in the real application - 'value' should only change after the user makes a selection.

Any suggestions on correcting this?

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(letter = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                 color = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'orange'),
                 value = 1:6)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tableOutput('show_df'),
  selectInput('letter', 'Pick a letter', choices = c('a', 'b')),
  radioButtons('color', 'Pick a color', choices = NULL, selected = character(0))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$show_df <- renderTable(df)

  observe({
    current_letter <- input$letter
    message(paste('Current letter is:', current_letter))
    updateRadioButtons(session,
                       'color',
                       choices = df$color[df$letter == current_letter],
                       selected = character(0))
  })

  observe({
    current_color <- input$color
    message(paste('Current color is:', current_color))
  })

  observe({
    current_value <- df$value[df$letter == input$letter & df$color == input$color]
    message(paste('Current value is:', current_value))
  })

}) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `renderUI` to re-render the radioButtons everytime you change selection. That way you can ensure that radioButtons will get reset.

Comment: It seems that the problem is related to have `df$color` as factors. I added to the `df` definition `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and it worked.

Comment: Please see me answer below.

Comment: Adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` didn't really fix the problem. It did get rid of an unrelated warning, but the issue remains. I will see if I can get a `renderUI` solution working.

Comment: The `renderUI` solution did not work either.. It seems the `selected = character(0))` part is just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It seems that `updateRadioButtons` change the widget but it does not update the value in `input$color`, so even if all the radio buttons are unselected, the last value selected is still there. Since your last observer is using the value of `color` and `letter`, when the user changes the value of `letter`, the observer will use also the value of `color` too (which is the last one). The problem persist even if you use a `renderUI`.

Below is your code modified, 1) it uses a data frame with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, 2) it isolates `input$letter` (you can also use `obsereEvent` instead), and 3) it adds a button to show the value of color at any time, so you can confirm that even updating the radio buttons, the `input$color` still has the last value used.

```R
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(letter = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                 color = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'orange'),
                 value = 1:6, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tableOutput('show_df'),
  selectInput('letter', 'Pick a letter', choices = c('a', 'b')),
  radioButtons('color', 'Pick a color', choices = NULL, selected = character(0)),
  actionButton("test", "showColor")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$show_df <- renderTable(df)

  observe({
    current_letter <- input$letter
    message(paste('Current letter is:', current_letter))
    updateRadioButtons(session,
                       'color',
                       choices = df$color[df$letter == current_letter],
                       selected = character(0))
  })

  observe({
    current_color <- input$color
    message(paste('Current color is:', current_color))
  })

  observe({
    current_value <- df$value[df$letter == isolate(input$letter) & df$color == input$color]
    message(paste('Current value is:', current_value))
  })

  observeEvent(input$test, {
    message(">>>color:", input$color)
  })  

}) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This doesn't work - first, setting stringsAsFactors = FALSE does not appear to have an effect, and second, if you select 'red', switch from 'a' to 'b', then hit the showColor button, it shows that red is still selected. This just re-demonstrates the problem, which indeed is the fact that input$color is not getting reset.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer explained, `input$color` is not updated, even when the radio buttons are reset.

One solution is to use a third reactive variable for color that can be changed by two different observers.
Below are: 1) a graphic showing the original problem, 2) the `reactiveValues` + `observeEvent`, and 3) a graphic showing the solution.

Note 1: Troubleshooting text was added to the code to show the outputs on the shiny interface.
Note 2: Graphics were made with an earlier solution. Original post had an extra conditional if/then statement.

[image: original result]

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(letter = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                 color = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'orange'),
                 value = 1:6)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tableOutput('show_df'),
  selectInput('letter', 'Pick a letter', choices = c('a', 'b')),
  radioButtons('color', label = 'Pick a color', 
                choices = NULL, selected = character(0)),
  HTML("Troubleshooting:"), br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("troubleshooting")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$show_df <- renderTable(df)

  observe({
    current_letter <- input$letter
    message(paste('Current letter is:', current_letter))
    updateRadioButtons(session,
                       'color',
                       choices = as.character(df$color[df$letter == current_letter]), 
                       selected = character(0))
   })

  myColor <- reactiveValues(current = NULL) #Create a reactiveValue
  #Define two observers that each can change the reactiveValue
  observeEvent(input$letter, {  
    myColor$current <- NULL
  })
  observeEvent(input$color, { 
    myColor$current <- input$color 
  })
  myValue <- reactive(df$value[df$letter == input$letter & df$color == myColor$current])

  observe({
    current_color <- input$color
    message(paste('Current color is:', current_color))
  })

  observe({
    current_value <- myValue()
    message(paste('Current value is:', current_value))
  })

  output$troubleshooting <- renderPrint({ list(
                              paste("current letter:", input$letter),
                              paste("current color:", input$color),
                              #Reactive color not originally included in pics.
                              paste("current reactive color:", myColor$current),  
                              paste("current value:", myValue() )
                                               )
                                       })

}) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result: The first `observeEvent` returns NULL when the letter is changed, effectively resetting the final value. `input$color` is still not reset. The second `observeEvent` returns the color when `input$color` is changed.

[image: correct output]

Comment: While this appears to work, it is just too convoluted - it should not be necessary to use counters and if statements to get a reactive expression to function correctly, and in the actual application it could get rather complicated. I appreciate your effort, but I have to believe there is a better way.

Comment: I agree, and hopefully someone posts a more concise method. The big issue is `input$color` does not reset. If you want to condense the above code, set the reactiveValue to NULL in the `input$letter` observer and to `color` in the `input$color` observer. Then you can get rid if the if/then statement and use the reactiveValue in place of `input$color`. At present, I don't think you can get around setting a 3rd variable.

Comment: I'll just edit the answer to show how it can be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the problem seems that you can't reset the input variable input$color. E.g. in the sample program below you can't perform the same action twice.

```
        ui <- fluidPage (
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel ( uiOutput('uiRadioButtons')),
            mainPanel    (uiOutput('action'))
        )) 
    server <- function(input, output) {
        output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = c ('a', 'b', 'c'), selected=character(0)) })
        n  <- 0
        observe({
            actionId <- input$actionId
            n <<- n+1
            if (!is.null(actionId)) {
                if (actionId=='a')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action A"))
                if (actionId=='b')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action B"))
                if (actionId=='c')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action C"))
                output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = c ('a', 'b', 'c'), selected=character(0)) })
            } else                  output$action  <- renderText ("actionId equals NULL")
        })
}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

As an alternative, if you can't reset the input variable to NULL, you may opt for dummy value which is shown and directly processed and replaced with the regular options. This is shown in the modified sample below.

```
    ui <- fluidPage (
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel (
            # radioButtons (inputId='objectId', label='selct object:', choices = c ('o1', 'o2', 'o3'), inline = TRUE),
            uiOutput('uiRadioButtons')
        ),
        mainPanel    (uiOutput('action'))
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    showActions <- function() {
        output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI ({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = c ('a', 'b', 'c'), selected=character(0)) })
    }
    showActions()
    n  <- 0
    observe({
        actionId <- input$actionId
        n <<- n+1
        if (!is.null(actionId)) {
            if (actionId=='dummy')  showActions ()
            else {
                if (actionId=='a')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action A"))
                if (actionId=='b')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action B"))
                if (actionId=='c')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action C"))
                output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = 'dummy') })
            }
        } else                  output$action  <- renderText ("actionId equals NULL")

    })
}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this solution may be too slow for remote applications. In that case, use an extra 'none' options (see radiobuttons help) or an extra actionButton and observe that button instead.
Hopefully, RStudio will implement the option to reset applicable input variables.

Comment: I think what we are up against here is the UI design principle that there shouldn't be such a thing as radio buttons with nothing selected. To represent that state you need to add an option called 'None selected' as one of the buttons. If we can accept that, then the only real problems here are that it is in fact possible to initialize radio buttons with nothing selected, and that the documentation claims it is possible to return to that state when it doesn't actually work. (Unfortunately our clients don't always agree with UI design principles, but that's a different problem.)